# Parquet three encodings means?

Tags: parquet

After reading the [document](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encodings.md),I know what every single encodings means.
But  I can't understand why one column has three encodings.

For example:

ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN,RLE

ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE

Answer (score 4):

This has to do that each column has at least three different arrays that are serialized.

- **repetition levels:** integer array that is used to specify (roughly) whether we have a single value in a row or the row consists of an array. Either `BIT_PACKED` or `RLE` encoded.
- **definition levels:** integer array to specify if a row is null and if so, on which nesting level. Either `BIT_PACKED` or `RLE` encoded.
- **data**: The actual data that is stored. Depending on the data this is on of the other encodings like `PLAIN` or `RLE_DICTIONARY`. As the data can also be split into several pages, you may get different encodings for each page. For example when a column is dictionary encoded, the first pages will be `PLAIN_DICTIONARY` or `RLE_DICTIONARY`. When the dictionary grows too large, the Parquet implementation may switch for all following pages to a different encoding, e.g. `PLAIN`.

Comment: So the example ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN,RLE.  BIT_PACKED is the repetition levels encoded, PLAIN is definition level encoded, RLE is the data encoded? Or the order can be affected by parquet versions.

Comment: Hello, I'm not understanding.. What the encoding order means? And when more than 3 encodings?

Answer (score 4):

```
row group 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x:  DOUBLE SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:4 SZ:1632/31635/19.38 VC:70000 ENC:RLE,BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[min: 1.0, max: 5.0, num_nulls: 10000]
y:  BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:1636 SZ:864/16573/19.18 VC:70000 ENC:RLE,BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[min: a, max: é, num_nulls: 10000]
z:  DOUBLE SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:2500 SZ:560097/560067/1.00 VC:70000 ENC:PLAIN,BIT_PACKED ST:[min: 2.0828331581679294E-7, max: 0.9999892375625329, num_nulls: 0]

    x TV=70000 RL=0 DL=1 DS: 5 DE:PLAIN_DICTIONARY
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    page 0:                   DLE:RLE RLE:BIT_PACKED VLE:PLAIN_DICTIONARY ST:[min: 1.0, max: 5.0, num_nulls: 10000] SZ:31514 VC:70000
```

I guess `ENC:BIT_PACKED,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,RLE` is just a set of all encoding (repetition levels, definition levels, data) used in all pages in a column chunk in a row group. Not sure if it is ordered.

Data encoding is probably the info you are intersted in. You can see from the page level `VLE:PLAIN_DICTIONARY` or the column chunk level `DS: 5 DE:PLAIN_DICTIONARY` which means the dictionary has 5 keys

- `DLE` - Definition level encoding.
- `RLE` - Repetition level encoding.
- `VLE` - Value encoding.